# How to test SNMP4J agent

Tags: java, get, set, snmp4j

I have the jar developed using the SNMP4J Agent source code. How can I test run the Agent ? I would like to include a MIB file and test the GET and SET methods. How can I write a test class for this?
Any link or tutorial will also be grateful
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can check [SNMP Simulator](http://snmpsim.sourceforge.net/), which is a free library to test SNMP agents and offers `MIB` based simulation

In general, you can create an SNMP client that use the MIB file you have to construct the requests and check if the response is valid, you can see [this tutorial](http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/creating-snmp-agent-server-in-java-using-snmp4j/) for example code on creating client/server SNMP agent.

Answer (score 0):

[NetSnmp](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/) is also useful to test your agent